# Is there a way to look at the last entry created in a case statement?

Tags: sql, increment, teradata, sequences

I have two columns, `last_usage` and `previous_last_usage`.

I want to create a third column, `seq_index`, that increments by 1 every time the condition `last_usage <> previous_last_usage` is met.

Is this possible?

Example:

```
LAST_USAGE PREVIOUS_LAST_USAGE SEQ_INDEX
1   1   0
0   1   1
0   0   1
0   0   1
1   0   2
1   1   2
0   1   3
0   0   3
0   0   3
```

Comment: Do you really want to save this as a third column, Couldn't you just add it in a Select Statement?
As in Select Last_Usage, Previous_Last_Usage, Case when Last_Usage <> Previous_Last_Usage then 1 else 0 end as Seq_index

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?  Is it acceptable to use a view to achieve this rather than storing the seq_index data in a column.

Comment: How is the row order determined?  Is there a primary key?

Comment: You'll also need some concept of sequence here. Either an identity (id) column or a time element to show order.

Comment: Mikey, this won't work as I need the column to increment not just equal 0 or 1. And I need the column stored as I need to then use it to group an MSUM function.

Myles, I am using Teradata and unfortunately I am not an sql expert and unsure as to what you mean.

Comment: Have a computed column that's 1 when diff and 0 when equal.. then sum it up using where <sequence> is less than equal to your desired row.

Comment: Andomar, I have a row_number column as well that shows the order. I should have mentioned this too.

Comment: Sam Yi, I think you're onto it there. Gonna try that now and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Sam Yi, your approach worked

Comment: @wilsonm2, terrific! Glad I can help.